# How to publish the entire target folder in azure pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I am working on a maven project, on building the project an ear file is generated in the target folder.

I want to setup a build pipeline where on running the pipeline, I want to publish the entire target folder. But only partial target folder is getting published without the ear file. How to publish the ear file inside target folder

How to do it?

Azure Pipeline command I am using:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Comment: Can you try wildcard? `PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/*'`

Comment: @RajeshSwarnkar it is showing this error.                     
Errors :Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: D:\a\1\a\*